# Managing two apps on bitbucket and linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I am fairly new to the repository management and deploying apps on server. Till now, I was working on single rails project, where I used to code on my local server and used to push it to bitbucket repository and then pull it on my linode server.

Now, I have one more app. I am not getting how to push it to bitbucket and pull it on linode so it won't get mixed with my previous code.

I have few questions:

1. Should I push the code to same repo on bitbucket and pull it on different folder on linode?
2. Or should I create another repo for new code?
3. If i create another repo, how to switch between two repo. I mean how the command for push will be so it will push the code to respective repo on bitbucket and how to pull so it will pull from desired repo.

It may sound very basic. I have search a lot on google, but may be my wording would be wrong, I am not getting how to handle two apps on bitbucket and how to pull them on server.

I will really appreciate it someone can help in doing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different repository for each app you create.

[Git remotes](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) are what points your repositories to different repositories on Bitbucket, or Github, or wherever else. Remotes are directory specific, so you can have each git repository pointed to it's own respective remote repository.

To see what repository your app is pointed at, run this in the terminal:

```
git remote -v
```

To add a repository as a remote, run this in the terminal:

```
git remote add origin https://[USER]@bitbucket.org/[USER]/[APPNAME].git
```

So, for your new app, you will want to:

1. create the repository on bitbucket
2. get the repository link (https://[USER]@bitbucket.org/[USER]/[APPNAME].git)
3. add the repository as a remote to your local machine
4. add the repository as a remote on your linode server

Now, when you push on your local machine from the app's directory, it will push to the new repository. And the same will be true for when you pull from your linode server.